# On mouseover / mousedown inside div should not close And outside div have to close

Tags: javascript, jquery

when user click - 'booking' container, 'open_contents' have to show.

1. when user mouseout of 'open_contents' container, it have to hide or click outside 'open_contents' or anywhere on 'body' of the page.
2. with present below code, above point 1 works ok. But, i have increment/decrement button on 'open_contents' container. When user click button, 'open_contents' getting hide on every click. it should not get hide when i click button element on 'open_contents' container.

Please let me know your available comments.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="booking">
    <div class="head">Ticket Booking</div>
</div>  

<div id="open_contents" class="open_contents">
    <div class="c_class">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default minus" id="group-btn-minus" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
        <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control group-input minus-plus-input" value="1" min="1" max="10">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default plus" id="group-btn-plus" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var $nonGroupBooking = $('.open_contents');

    if (!$nonGroupBooking.is(e.target)
        && $nonGroupBooking.has(e.target).length === 0);
    {
        $nonGroupBooking.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have bound the onclick event to `$(document)`, all elements inside `$(document)` on click will also be considered as `$(document)`.clicked

To stop the event bubbling up the event, you could use e.stopPropagation, read more on https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Here please try my example - https://jsfiddle.net/w07gnzgg/1/

I changed the `$(".booking").on("click")` behavior to show the `.open_contents` and also disabled `$(".open_contents").on("mouseleave")` event by default

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click handler to the document to hide the contents, but also add a click handler to the contents that stops propagation (prevents the click event from reaching the document handler).

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    $('.open_contents').hide();
});

$('.open_contents').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```